# JQuery's .animate() not working in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As simple as it is, I am wondering how is it possible that my little div is not getting any bigger. Anyone knows why? 
(p.s. I've tried to run it on every browser and i really can't find any syntax errors, I'm getting blind.. or just older)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#abc").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      left: '250px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#abc {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="abc"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't have jquery included, yet you're using it's functions.

Comment: Open the browser's JavaScript console and look at the error messages there.

Answer (score 0):

the only issue with you code is using jquery and javascript selector together which is throwing a console error and causing animate to misbehave

```
$(document.getElementById("abc")
```

use only jquery selector for animate method

```
$("#abc")
```

plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/kd31upaEE5p7YBK0st3M?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#abc").animate({
height:"500px",
width:"500px",
}, 5000, function() {
});
});
```

***NOTE!*** That you have to include JQuery in your page.